# C++ std::bind to std::function, what went wrong in VS2015?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, stl

I was a user of VS2013 and I often use initialization as follows and it was working like a charm:

```
MyClass::MyClass myRoutine(){
    std::function<double(double)> oFunc = std::bind(&Myclass::myfunction, this, std::placeholders::_1);
}

MyClass::MyClass myfunction(double & inX){
    return 0;
}
```

I decided to upgrade to VS2015, but the compiler reports errors:

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,double (__thiscall MyClass::* )(double &),MyClass *const ,const std::_Ph<1> &>' to 'std::function<double (double)>'

What happened?

Comment: Why do you place `double(double &)` function into `double(double)`? Also, why do you use `bind` instead of lambda? Lambdas are much better, easier to debug and compile to better code.

Comment: The only reason I used bind is because it worked in VS2013... Of course , if there is a better way of doing it, I m listening

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was supported by VS2013 as well: `... oFunc = [this](double &x){ return myfunction(x); };`. I can turn this into an answer if you want.

Comment: An answer explaining why it works in VS2013, plus a better way to write it will be welcome

Comment: why what works? Lambdas or your old code?

Comment: The code that I posted works in VS2013, but not in VS2015. A lambda version would be additional to complete the answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function takes its argument by reference (`double &`) while your are trying to assign it to the function with signature that takes by value (`double`).

This has compiled in VS2013 most likely due to conformance bugs (maybe some weird interaction with non-const ref to temporary MSVC extension). Basically it's not a valid C++ code. VS2015 is leagues ahead of previous VSes (VS2017 is even more so) in terms of standard support and conformance so this faulty code is no longer compiling.

Anyway, std::bind is almost entirely obsoleted by lambdas, which should be supported by VS2010+. They produce better code, better warnings/errors, easier to write and debug.

For example, your code could'be rewritten like this:

`std::function<double(double)> oFunc = [this](double x){ return myfunction(x); };`

Or like this if you actually want to pass by reference:

`std::function<double(double &)> oFunc = [this](double &x){ return myfunction(x); };`

Notice how shorter and simpler it is.

Comment: Lambdas are fine for one line functions. What do you do when you want a function with a lot more code in it? Have a lambda that simply calls another function? If you are going to do that you might as well use std::bind. Or maybe put the full function in the lambda. That's extremely confusing, having a function defined inside another function!

Comment: @AlastairG "If you are going to do that you might as well use std::bind." Why? As this (and numerous other similar questions, not to mention general experience) show, the better approach is "If you have std::bind you might as well replace it lambda". Lambda approach is easier to read and understand, often shorter, generates better code, avoids conformance bugs and produces sane error messages (and faster to compile and more flexible to boot). There is a really small niche there std::bind is still useful (and even that is arguable).

Comment: Whenever I have read code, in any language, with lambdas, it is only readable if you can put the lambda on a very few lines and none of the code needs any context. A more complex class function using member variables is very hard to write as a lambda without being very unreadable. Or at least using any indentation/style that I have ever been asked to code to. Essentially I find lambdas very hard or impossible to read, especially if there is any complexity to them. You are basically writing a function inside a function call! A simple call like `RegisterForEventX(my_callback) is very readable.

Comment: However, a call like `OnEventX({int i; for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { etc. etc.` is completely unreadable, and if it has many levels (2 or more) of indentation on top of however many levels of indentation there already are when the call is made then the code is even more of a mess. I am looking at examples from my code where I use std::bind and I cannot see how I could possible implement the 100 line function (with switch statement) that gets called, as a readable lambda.

Comment: @AlastairG As I said, the solution involving lambda is -- among numerous over advantages -- shorter and more readable that the std::bind one. Compare them yourself. It's about 20% shorter and easily fits on the single line (not that the std::bind version couldn't be made shorter, but that's not the point). I don't get where your idea of a 100-line lambda function is coming from.

Comment: I realise now that you are just using the lambda to call a single function rather than implementing the function in its entirety in the function. Doesn't that add an extra layer of function call though, thus making it less efficient? With std::bind you generate a function pointer that can be called directly. With your lambda you generate a function pointer that calls another function. An extra stack frame.

Comment: @AlastairG std::bind doesn't generate a function pointer. It generates "bind expression" of unspecified type. It is at best jsut a functor with extra stack frame, but usually it's much worse, since all the TMP makes it opaque to the compiler. Lambdas, on the other hand, are optimized rather well by the compilers. Note that there is no way to avoid the additional indirection for the case like in OP in general case (you need to store this pointer somewhere), but lambda still gives much better codegen: https://godbolt.org/z/bj8Wff.  Btw, clang is able to optimize it out completely, impressive!

Comment: Very convincing. Thankyou for taking the time to explain it. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Function signatures do not match: `double(double)` vs `double(double&)`. Hence the compilation error. One of these needs to be changed, e.g.:

```
double MyClass::myfunction(double inX){
    return 0;
}
```